# basic entity ID , integer or text?

Tags: sqlite

new to SQLite, teaching a class and am wondering about entity ids. If you have only numbers in your id, should you choose integer OR does it ever make sense to choose text as a data type? or are integers used only for values that can be used for calculations? what if there is a number and a letter (text?)? thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Your entity Id primary key and auto increments so your id should be integers otherwise your id can be varchar or text whatever you desired.

As you said have only numbers in ids so that must be integer. if you sure about id has will be always number.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, i can choose text or integer? is there a benefit to choosing one over the other? thanks!

Comment: you are welcome as i know you are new here. so if you agreed so can you accept it as your ans. thank you...

Comment: yup either if you choose integer so you can set it as auto increment than you never worry about that. if your ids always have number. or if you chose text so you need to insert id evry time with the each row. so i guess you should choose integer.